# javascript with textarea input correspondingly text area output - no button clicks

Tags: javascript

I have seen some pages in which we can input in textarea and correspondingly an output gets displayed for it
no button clicks in between , see an example here http://ntools.infoexpo.in/p/html-to-xml-encoder_4042.html

how to apply this type in the below code
html:

```
<textarea  id="source"  placeholder="Text Entry."></textarea>
<p id="result"> </p>
```

js

```
function myFunction()
{
var str = document.getElementById('source').value;

var len = str.length;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<textarea>"+len+"</textarea>";

}
```

Comment: So what you want actually?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
function showtext(val)
{
  var textstring =  val.value;
  var textlength = textstring.length;
//alert(val.value);
$('#len').html(textlength); 
$('#two').html(textstring);
}
</script>

<textarea id="one" onKeyUp="showtext(this)"></textarea>
<textarea id="two"><span id="len"></span></textarea>
```

Comment: Include an entire library to select an element? What's wrong with `getElementById()`?

Comment: Just thought this would be helpful in case of any extended requirement.  Otherwise, getElementById will suffice :)

Answer (score 0):

It is pure `javascript`,I think you should learn a bit of javascript,but i will show you the sample

```
<textarea id="t1" onkeyup="document.getElementById('t2').value=this.value" ></textarea>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="t2" ></textarea>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WA8qz/1/)

Comment: so for example in first textarea i take userinput and in second textarea want to show result - the length of text -- what should i do?

Comment: @Sreeraj: that is what is in the DEMO,did you check the demo ?

Comment: how to apply it on this        html-  <textarea  id="source"  placeholder="Text Entry."   ></textarea> <p id="result"> </p>
                        js-  function myFunction()

{
var str = document.getElementById('source').value;

var len = str.length;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<textarea>"+len+"</textarea>";

}